# incompatible types: String cannot be converted to OnInitializationCompleteListener

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android Studio 2021.1 and strangely after updating my libraries earlier I get this error when I compile my application `incompatible types: String cannot be converted to OnInitializationCompleteListener`

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_banner_id));
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);     //The line that returns the error to me
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently google has changed the way of integrating ads into apps. I went to the site and applied the new rules to my code and everything was back to normal.

For those who will encounter the same problem simply replace your code with this one

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_banner_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Typecasting

```
mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it does not change

Comment: please follow this, https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner?hl=en-US and https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en-US#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk

Answer (score 1):

`MobileAds.initialize()` has a signature:

```
public static void initialize (Context context, OnInitializationCompleteListener listener)
```

It receiving an instance of OnInitializationCompleteListener as a second argument.
In your code you try to send a string as a second parameter.
You should change second parameter in this line

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_banner_id));
```

to instance of OnInitializationCompleteListener.